# Problemas con el action de php o la página de "aterrizaje"

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo un formulario con campos validados con JS, el formulario esta con el

```
method="post"
```

la información se tiene que almacenar en otro servidor, asi que en el action de mi formulario tengo la "URL" de llegada para poder insertar los datos del formulario a la base de datos, tengo el action asi:

```
action="http://example.com/2018/sitios/example/handle.php">
```

Pero al momento de aterrizar aparece que "no puedo acceder a este sitio web" no se que estaré haciendo mal, solo necesito ayuda.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tienes reglas de CORS?

Comment: ¿Que tiene que ver esto con mysql?

Comment: Agrega el error tàl cual se muestra a la hora de intentar mandar la informacion al server, si es un problema de CORS es facil de solucionar.

Comment: Hola exactamente me sale este error No se puede acceder a este sitio web Es posible que la página web http://example.com/2018/sitios/example/handle.php esté temporalmente inactiva o que se haya trasladado definitivamente a otra dirección.
ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form action="http://example.com/2018/sitios/example/handle.php" method="POST">
 .
 .
 .
       <input class="form-btn" name="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar" />
    </form>
```

Normalmente la forma de enviar un formulario es está, que este validado con JS es independiente del envio en si del formulario.

Puede ser que tengas problemas con el servidor externo que no permita la recepcion de información por post

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo en lo que dices del server externo.